# Multi-threading Code stuck with Form.ShowDialog() statement

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am new to C# and was trying to write a form a test a network connection. The idea is that put the connection part in a thread and show a progress dialog during the connection. The following is my code:

```
Form_TestingConnection testingConnection = new Form_TestingConnection();
Thread t1 = new Thread(TestConnection);

try
{
testingConnection.ShowDialog();
t1.Start();    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error(ex);
if (MessageBox.Show(
    Resources.message_connection_issue,
    Resources.title_connection_issue,
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    loginSuccessful = false;
}
}
```

TestConnection is a method to test the connection and set a static member loginSuccessful based on result. The issue I am having now is that the code stuck with testingConnection.ShowDialog(). Whenever it executes to this place, it never goes forward. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you wanna move your thread to the testingConnection form and have it start in the Form_Load event ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) shows the form modally. This means that the form will show, all other forms will be disabled, and the `ShowDialog` function will not return until the modal dialog is closed.

Use [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) instead. This shows the form modeless. When you do that the `Show` function returns immediately and the form stays open.

You can think of `ShowDialog` as being synchronous and `Show` as being asynchronous.

Make sure that any methods in the thread which need to update progress on the form are called using `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to ensure that they run in the context of the main UI thread.

Finally, your code as it stands does not wait until the thread has done its work. The try/catch block only wraps the form show and the beginning of the thread's execution (`t1.Start()`). When you call `Start` on a thread that call returns asynchronously and the thread continues to do its work. I'm not quite sure what your code is trying to do, but I suspect that the `catch` block should be inside the thread.

Comment: Thanks David! Your answer makes a lot of sense. This has puzzled me for hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access any GUI component which belongs to a thread from another thread  you should use **InvokeRequired** to avoid the cross thread exceptions